# Quicktime is installing when it is already installed

Tags: wix, quicktime

I have a WIX installer bundle that has QuickTime as a prereq. I trying to check a registry key to determine if it's already installed but it always comes back false.

The log shows...

[08B4:040C][2015-07-06T10:50:14]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Media\QuickTime' 
[08B4:040C][2015-07-06T10:50:14]i000: Setting numeric variable 'QuickTimeFound64' to value 0 
[08B4:040C][2015-07-06T10:50:14]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Media\QuickTime'

The registry is ...

[image]

The code is ...

```
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Media\QuickTime" Result="exists" Variable="QuickTimeFound64" Win64="yes" />
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Media\QuickTime" Result="exists" Variable="QuickTimeFound32" Win64="no" />

    <Chain>
        <PackageGroupRef Id="PackageGroup_NetFx35Redist"/>
        <PackageGroupRef Id="PackageGroup_NetFx40Redist"/>
        <PackageGroupRef Id="PackageGroup_SQLServer2012"/>

        <ExePackage Id="Package_QuickTime" Cache="no" Compressed="$(var.Compressed)" 
                      Description="Apple QuickTime 7" DownloadUrl="$(var.GuruDownloadRepo)/{2}" 
                      SourceFile="..\Prerequisites\QuickTimeInstaller.exe" 
                      Name="Prerequisites\QuickTimeInstaller.exe" 
                      Permanent="yes" DisplayName="Apple QuickTime 7" 
                      DetectCondition="QuickTimeFound64 AND QuickTimeFound32" />
```

I have tried including "Wow6432Node" in the 64bit path but it didn't make any difference.

Can anyone tell me why both of the searches are coming back as false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
SOFTWARE\Clients\Media\QuickTime
```

instead of

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Media\QuickTime
```

because HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE is specified in the `Root` attribute.